# Network around rectangle with text inside in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create a visualization as shown in the image:

[image]

A rectangle box with text inside it and network around the box.
I am trying to use D3, and I am stuck at the first step of putting text inside the rectangle. I found out that we cannot put text inside a rectangle or circle in d3. Is there a container or something like that in d3 to put text inside and make the network around them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a text element under a `<rect>` / `<circle>` / `<polygon>` / `<path>`...

Add a `<g>` element. Then, add a `<rect>` and a `<text>` under the `<g>`:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(100,50)');

g.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -60)
  .attr('y', -40)
  .attr('width', 120)
  .attr('height', 80)
  
g.append('text')
  .text('This is a text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');
```

```css
rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

text {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 16px;
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg />
```